# X architecture db2 to connect 2 databases

Tags: command-line, db2, xa

I am just a beginner and I was trying to learn how to use the x Architecture to connect two db2 databases. I know some stuff about XA like, it acts like an API between different databases. I was wondering if someone has some resource with all the xa db2 commands and I could try them out. I think I cannot use command line for xa, I need to write an SQL application. Please, correct me where I am wrong. Thank you. Every answer is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you not using db2 federation?